# Elastic Search : How to search string starting with some characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanted to search for data from elastic search, where data is matching from the start first n characters.

below is dataset/data I have into the ES index

```
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 47,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "search_suggestions",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "VW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcw==",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "VW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcw==",
                    "name": "India",
                    
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "search_suggestions",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "RW1iYXNzeSBvZiB0aGUgViwgREMsIFVTQQ==",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "RW1iYXNzeSBvZiB0aGUgViwgREMsIFVTQQ",
                    "name": "Maharashtra, India",
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "search_suggestions",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "TWFoaSBCYXpB",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "TWFoaSBCYXpB",
                    "name": "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
                 }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried search by using query/term/prefix/wildcard methods. I wanted to find names starting with "Ind*" but in response, it returns strings which are matching at any location within the string. I wanted results only starting with "Ind*" only I should get "India" as result not others.

Kindly suggest the way how can I query ES to get above expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response, the query returns strings which are matching at any location within the string, because the string gets separated into the individual token (based on the standard analyzer). Therefore, it will match all the documents that contain **India** in any position and not just at the beginning of the `name` field

**Analyze API**

```
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "Maharashtra, India"
}
```

Following tokens are generated:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "maharashtra",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "india",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

To achieve your use case you need to set the `name` field as that of `keyword` type

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name": {
        "value": "Ind"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65119778",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "VW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcw==",
          "name": "India"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Does ‘prefix’ support special characters?